# Determine the duration of H.264 frame

Tags: h.264, rtmp

Single RTMP video message usually carries one H.264 frame together with the timestamp delta. Usually the timestamp delta represents the duration of the single video frame, eg. 40ms for 25FPS video. This allows to compute the duration of the stream by calculating the sum of the RTMP video deltas in stream.

However, for some encoders (e.g. Wirecast) there are occasionally RTMP video messages that contain just one H.264 frame but the timestamp delta is the multiple of the single video frame duration (e.g. 120ms, 160ms etc).

Does it mean that in some cases a single H.264 frame can represent multiple video frames? Which H.264 frame meta information (field) represents this?How to distinguish that for a selected frame the timestamp delta should be different from the the duration of a single video frame? I would like to correctly calculate the presentation timestamp for a single H.264 frame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are likely dropped frames. For RTMP you should always assume variable frame rate (no matter what onMetadata said)

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense. Would it be possible to fill the gap (dropped frames) with some artificial H.264 frames (e.g. cloned frame that carries the higher timestamp indicating missing frames, or by generating Filler Data frame)? This would be a way to preserve constant frame rate.

Comment: It's possible, but it would be a lot of work. (Basically rewriting the bitstream) it would be time better spent fixing the player to correctly play variable frame rate streams.